# Removing Gmail from phone

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I understand that my Android 'phone needs Google to operate but why must I have a Gmail account?
I don't use my email linked to Gmail but get a lot of mail; I choose to use AOL for all mail as I have done for 20+ years.
Can I close my email on Google without affecting the operation of the 'phone?
Details

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your GMail account you can simply ignore it.

On Android you can uninstall/disable the GMail app so you won't get any notifications. As GMail is a system app on Google Android devices you can't uninstall, just disable it.

It may happen that GMail is re-enabled again if you install a system update/upgrade. Then you have to disable it again.

Comment: Thanks, I have disabled the app and will keep checking to see if it re-enables.

Comment: But also make sure that in your Google profile , your AOL account is mentioned as standby account else you may miss out on security related issues pertaining to your account +1

Comment: John, if the answer meets your expectations, you can [accept it](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)